# More words in inputText

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hi how to add more words between

```
if(inputText!.text == "motorka"){
```

i want to add "Motorka" and "MOTORKA". But the following does not work:

```
if(inputText!.text == "motorka", "Motorka", "MOTORKA"){
```

How can I check for more than just one string?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
  let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
  let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
  let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

  if(touchedNode.name == "checkbutton"){
    if(inputText!.text == "motorka"){
      runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("correct.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
      correct.hidden = false
      inputText!.hidden = true
      check.hidden = true
      let nextLevel = level2(size: size)
      nextLevel.scaleMode = scaleMode
      let transitionType = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.4)
      let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.9)
      let action = SKAction.runBlock {
        view?.presentScene(nextLevel, transition: transitionType)
      }
      self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))
    }
}
```

Comment: In other languages you would have to create a list (or array or set) and ask if the value is contained (function names like `contains()` or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the boolean OR `||`:

```
if(inputText!.text == "motorka" || inputText!.text == "Motorka" || inputText!.text == "MOTORKA") { ... }
```

However to make it look nicer and in some cases to be more performant you should create a temporary variable for the text and then run the checks against that variable:

```
let text = inputText!.text
if(text == "motorka" || text == "Motorka" || text == "MOTORKA") { ... }
```

You might even want to remove the OR all together and go make use of the `lowercaseString` porperty, which will match every upper/lowercase varaitione of the word `"motorka"`:

```
let text = inputText!.text.lowercaseString
if(text == "motorka") { ... }
```

Comment: thanks, I tested  if(inputText!.text == "motorka" || "Motorka" || "MOTORKA")

Comment: so it does work with my solution? or do you need more? If it did, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: In the OPs question all the strings are different upper/lower case versions of the same string. Using lowercaseString is a much better solution. (Voted.) That would catch **all** the possiblities: ("mortorka", "mOrToRkA", etc.)

Comment: @DuncanC yes, thats why i included it, i am however not sure that that actually is what OP wants, gut it might very well be the case

Answer (score 0):

Using an `NSArray` and `containsObject`:

```
let text = inputText!.text
let wordList = ["motorka", "Motorka", "MOTORKA"] as NSArray
if wordList.containsObject(text) {
    ...
}
```